# MySQL stored procedure for table insert error

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have below basic table:

```
    create table hobbies (
    id int primary key auto_increment,
    name varchar(32) unique);
```

And I am trying to create a stored procedure to insert a new row in this table, like below:

```
    delimiter //
    create procedure add_hobby(hobby varchar(32))
    begin
    insert into hobbies(name) values(hobby);
    end
    delimiter //

    call add_hobby('randomHobby');
```

When I call the procedure like above I am getting message "An unexpected error occured". I am running the queries on db-fiddle.com, MySQL ver 8.0. Could anyone offer some guidance if I've done something wrong or missed something? I can mention that procedure with select operation and no parameters works. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like a bug in db-fiddle. Try in [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=65e5db35eb8c74c71feabdc511dccd9a).

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your delimiter to begin with and then reset it at the end
for your parameters you need to set weather they are IN or out then the name and the type

```
delimiter //
create procedure add_hobby(IN hobby varchar(32))
begin
insert into hobbies(name) values(hobby);
end//
delimiter ;
```

Comment: Thanks. I am however still getting the same error when I invoke the call:                    
       call add_hobby('someHobby');                                                                                            Without the call the code is run successfully, same as with my code posted initially.

Comment: Just this: "An unexpected error occured." What dbms are you using? I just need an unsophisticated free and error-free MySQL tool where I can test some queries and procedures/triggers for school work.

Comment: i get the same error on db-fiddle but works on mysql 8